# Rails password reset mailer test undefined method `html_safe' error (using Clearance gem)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, actionmailer, minitest

I'm trying to create a mailer test in Rails to check the password reset mailer that [Clearance sends](https://github.com/thoughtbot/clearance).

The default view for the password reset mailer has this link in it:

```
<%= link_to "Change my password",
    edit_user_password_url(@user, token: @user.confirmation_token.html_safe) %>
```

It seems like calling `html_safe` is a good thing, but in my mailer test I keep getting this error:

```
Minitest::UnexpectedError: ActionView::Template::Error: undefined method `html_safe' for nil:NilClass
Did you mean?  html_safe?
```

I can't figure out why this is happening. Here's my mailer test so far:

```
require "test_helper"

class PasswordResetMailerTest < ActionMailer::TestCase
  setup do
    @user = users(:elvis)
  end

  test "password reset email" do
    email = ClearanceMailer.change_password(@user)

    # Send the email, then test that it got queued
    assert_emails 1 do
      email.deliver_now
    end
  end
end
```

Why is that causing an `undefined method html_safe` error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you can do to fix the issue is:

```
<%= link_to "Change my password",
edit_user_password_url(@user, token: @user.confirmation_token&.html_safe) %>
```

Using the `&.` operator so if it is nil then it will not throw exception. The reason for exception could be calling the mailer directly so in you test you have called `ClearanceMailer.change_password(@user)` and this email is sent when the user clicks on Forgot Password or something else (means there is a process which happens before sending the email) which sets the confirmation token on the user and when the email is sent `@user.confirmation_token` is present. So to fix this you can:

1. Use the `&.` as specified above
2. Call the method called before this to set the confirmation token
3. Or you can set a random confirmation token manually `user.update(confirmation_token: 'random text')` as this is just a test and you are checking that the email should be delivered.

Comment: Thanks! The `&` operator was not needed. It simply was because I hadn't generated the token on the user yet, so adding `@user.update(confirmation_token: 'random text')` to my setup did the trick. Thanks so much!